# Convert old 3d model in DWB format?

Tags: 3d

I've got some old 3d models in a ".DWB" file format.  The application that created them was called Designer's Workbench by Coryphaeus Software.  I think the company is long gone.
My goal is to somehow convert the models into a format that can be imported into Google Sketchup so that I can use them in Google Earth.  Any ideas?
Thanks for the help!
amb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach would be to find something else that could read those files and then export them from that.

Assuming that you can't do that you need to follow something like the following procedure (reverse engineering):

Get a *very* simple model (a 1x1x1 cube centred on a known point, not 0,0,0) in DWB format.

Open the file in a hex editor and examine it to find the cube.

Work out which codes mean position, size etc.

Repeat for other models (cylinder, line, etc.)

When you've done this for enough files, run the models you want to import through the process and see what comes out. Does it resemble the input? If not repeat the process tweaking your code until it does.

I'm sorry I can't be more specific, but you need the file format.

Comment: Hey Chris:
Thanks for the quick and helpful reply!
I was hoping somebody would come up with the intermediate tool to do the conversion from DWB to a Sketchup friendly format.  My Google searches haven't turned anything up.
I should've noted in my question that I don't have access to the Designer Workbench tool, just the models themselves.
Thanks!
amb

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I just changed the file extension to .skp and it opened in Sketchup